# Material paginator on dynamically set mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator

I have a table and for each row expanded there is another mat table.
When I expand one of my rows of my first table, the row is expanded and it displays the second table, fine.

I want to apply a paginator, so I added `<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]"></mat-paginator>` under my table in the HTML template.

My template :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="users">
  <mat-card class="example-card" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <mat-card-title>
      <p class="mat-title">Users: {{users.length}}</p>
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>

      <div style="width: 400px; margin: auto;" #chartElement></div>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
      </mat-form-field>

      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows matSort>

        <!-- First name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First name</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.firstName}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- last name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last name</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.lastName}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- email Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.email}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Userid Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>User ID</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.userId}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Quot Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="numberOfQuot">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Quots</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.numberOfQuot}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Class Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="numberOfQuotThirtyDays">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Rank</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
            <span><img alt="rank" src="../../assets/images/classes/{{user.rank}}.png" /></span>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
            <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="user == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">

              <div style="width: 70%;">
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="userDetailsDataSource">

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let userActivity"> {{userActivity.action}} </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="onTenant">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>On tenant</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let userActivity"> {{userActivity.tenant.tenantName}} </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="onProject">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>On project</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let userActivity"> {{userActivity.actionDetails.projectName}} </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="userDetailsColumns"></tr>
                  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: userDetailsColumns;"></tr>

                </table>

                <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]"></mat-paginator>       
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let user; let i =dataIndex; columns: displayedColumns;" class="example-element-row"
          [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === user" (click)="clickOnRowUser(user)">
        </tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>

      </table>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</ng-container>
```

My clickOnRowUser function in my component :

```
clickOnRowUser(user) {
    if (this.expandedElement == user) {
      this.expandedElement = "";
    }
    else {
      this.expandedElement = user;
    }

    this.userDetailsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(user.activities);
    this.userDetailsDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  }
```

But paginator is not working

Comment: i tried setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator); but not working

Comment: And if i place my paginator at the very end of my template HTML it works

Comment: So this question is solved?

Comment: that's not what i want, i want the paginator to be just under the table

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: that's what i am trying to do, i am trying to reproduce my problem but i can't :

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-liephj?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.ts